# js with express and prisma- delete function is still triggering insert (prisma create function on server side)

Tags: javascript, express, prisma

I am using express with js to delete a record from my azure sql database (prisma is the orm). The post method worked on the leads route. The delete did not work...it is posting empty record to Leads table rather than triggering the delete function on the server side:

--Client Side Script
document.querySelector('#delete_leads_form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#delete_leads_form input, #delete_leads_form select')

const payload = {};

inputs.forEach(input=>{
    payload[input.name] = input.value
})

async function deleteReq(){
    try {
        
    const response = await fetch('https://hh-events-internal.herokuapp.com/lead', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    } )

    const responseJson = await response.json()

    console.log('response', responseJson)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

}

deleteReq()
```

})

I have tried changing the client side method to DELETE, and no luck.

Comment: Can you share your express code? How are you defining the delete route?